# Formatting milliseconds in JS stopwatch

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I basically have a finished stopwatch that works except for the milliseconds. I only want to show 2 digits for the milliseconds, but I'm having an issue. This is the function I used to format my time output:

```
function timeFormatter(timeInMilliseconds) {
  var time = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
  var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
  var milliseconds = time.getMilliseconds().toString().slice(0, 2);

  if (minutes.length < 2) { minutes = '0' + minutes; }
  if (seconds.length < 2) { seconds = '0' + seconds; }
  if (milliseconds.length < 2) { milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds; }

  return minutes + ' : ' + seconds + ' . ' + milliseconds;
}
```

**The problem**:

When I give this function an input of `3093` for example, the output is `00 : 03 . 93`

When I give the function an input of `3105` (which should be greater than the previous), the output is `00 : 03 . 10`. In other words, my stopwatch is going back a few milliseconds.

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when u give input as 3105. your output will be 00 :  3 .105, since you are taking only 2 digits from milliseconds it is getting converted to 00 : 3 .10 you need to change your logic accordingly to handle this.

Comment: Simplest is `('00' + milliseconds).slice(-3)`.

Comment: I understand why the issue is happening, I'm just not sure how to fix it while only using 2 digits for milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var hundredths = (time.getMilliseconds()/10).toFixed(2);
```

You're not really looking for milliseconds (thousandths of a second, which can be three digits, 0-999), you're looking for hundredths.  So you take the milliseconds, divide by 10, and round.  That'll give you the number of hundredths of a second.  If you need a leading zero, you can add it:

```
var hundredths= (time.getMilliseconds()/10).toFixed(0);
if(hundredths.length < 2) hundredths= "0" + hundredths;
```

Note that `Number.prototype.toFixed` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed...I'm not sure what time zone you're in, but it is 10:30p here on the west coast, so if you're in the US, you're working late!

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to say I think I'm still having an issue with my output (it still isn't 2 digits). If I give the code an input of `3093`, I end up with the result `"00 : 03 . 9.30"`. This is my current code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab7750f8f95d4e0ea506

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault.  It should be `toFixed(0)`; you're trying to kill the digits past the decimal point, not get two extra digits.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. This pretty much works, the only issue is when the number is something like `3998`, which will result in `00 : 03 . 100`. Is there any way I can fix this case where it leads to 3 decimal places? I appreciate all the help you've been giving.

Comment: Ahh, the rounding up is causing a problem. You could truncate after rounding like you were doing originally (if the resulting string is 3 digits). That's probably your best bet... You want the rounding behaviour, because 999 is closer to 1000 than it is to 99.

Comment: Ok, yeah that makes sense. Thanks for taking the time :). I'm in EST in the US, so its 3:00 AM haha I spent quite awhile working on this little thing. Really appreciate it, you saved me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple *pad* function like:

```js
/* Pad num with leading zeros to minimum length
** If number length is equal to or greater than minimum length,
** return it unmodified.
**
** @param {number} num    - number to pad
** @param {number} length - minimum length of padded number
*/
function pad(num, length) {
  if ((''+num).length >= length) return num;
  var lead = '0' + new Array(length).join('0')
  return (lead + num).slice(-length);
}

document.write(pad(23,5)); // 00023
document.write('<br>' + pad(223,2)); // 223
```

so then you remove all those *if* statements and use:

```
 return pad(minutes,2) + ' : ' + pad(seconds,2) + ' . ' + pad(milliseconds,3);
```

Comment: The thing is I want the milliseconds to only show 2 digits, not 3.

Comment: Then do `pad(Math.round(milliseconds/10), 2)`. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Just try this code For Start, Stop And Reset the Timer

```
var elem = document.getElementById("my-stopwatch");
var timer = new Stopwatch(elem, {delay: 10});

// start the timer
timer.start();

// stop the timer
timer.stop();

// reset the timer
timer.reset();
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I didn't implement my Stopwatch like that.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question?